# Nested Node in CSS

Tags: css, sass

I have something like

```
<div>
  <div class="a">content</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="a">content</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="a">content</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to apply an adjacent sibling type rule to class a, given that they are contained within another element?

For example, I'd like to be able to do:

```
a + a { font-size: smaller; }
```

to apply a rule to all but the first div. However, this won't work with the traditional + operator, because it only applies to directly adjacent elements.

Comment: No, CSS rules can never go "up".

Comment: You'd have to give your wrapping `div`s a class too, and then use the adjacent sibling selector.

Comment: You're looking for the "cousin" selector, which unfortunately does not exist.

Comment: Are you allowed to wrap this nested structure within it's own div? if so it's possible to acheive what you want with the nth-child selector.

Comment: `div + div > .a` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[General sibling combinator `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)***

```css
div ~ div .a{       /* or: div ~ div > .a Or rather div.parent ~ div.parent .a */
  font-size:smaller;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="a">content</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="a">content</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="a">content</div>
</div>
```

preferabily use a parent class selector to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do it in pure CSS is give the parent `divs` a class:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">content</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">content</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper + .wrapper a {
styles here
}
```

You could also use Javascript/jQuery to target the parents of your `.a divs`. You might have to combine jQuery `each()` and `parent()`

Answer (score -1):

```
a:not(:first-of-type){font-size: smaller;}
```

Comment: Did you test this? Syntactically, I guess it should be `a:not(:first-of-type)`. But it won't work anyway, because **all** the `a` tags are `first-of-type`, since `first-of-type` refers to position under parent.